# How to get coordinates of joints in Kinect?

Tags: coordinates, kinect

I am learning about Kinect and I have a problem. I want to write to a text file the coordinate of joints of the skeleton but i don't know how to do that. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, but it has one problem with 'skeletons'in this line:
Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s);

System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"F:\Kinect Install\SkeletonBasics-WPF\Coordinates.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        int frame = 0;
        Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

```
    public void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        frame++;
        using (SkeletonFrame sFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (sFrame == null) return;

            sFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
            Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s);
            if (skeleton == null)
                return;

            if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(joint.Position.X + "," + joint.Position.Y + "," + joint.Position.Z + ",");
                }
                //writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the SDK:

```
using System.IO;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@path);
int frames = 0;

...

void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    frames++;
    using (SkeletonFrame sFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrameData())
    {
        if (sFrame == null)
            return;

        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

        Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons
                                where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                                select s);
        if (skeleton == null)
            return;

        if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            writer.Write("{0} {1}@", frames, timestamp);//I dont know how you want to do this
            foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {
                writer.Write(joint.Position.X + "," + joint.Position.Y + "," joint.Position.Z + ",");
            }
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

This takes the joints of a detected skeleton, and writes them to a file without specifying their relative joint, but it is in the default order of the joint types. Note this is the distance from the kinect sensor.

Comment: Thank you, but it has one problem with 'skeletons'

Comment: @iamatsundere181 Can you elaborate?